# Неправильно использую модуль __str__ . Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x

Неправильно использую модуль `__str__` . Срабатывает только модуль `__str__`, который находится в class `Dict()`. А в class `Card()`, `__str__`  не срабатывает.
Вот что результат после запуска кода[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ни как не могу понять в чём проблема, буду рад помощи. Код ниже

```
class Card():
    """ A playing card. """
    RANKS = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
    "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
    SUITS = ["c", "d", "h", "s"]

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.rank + self.suit
        return rep

class Dict():
    """Make the dictionary of all cards"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def __str__(self):
        rep = "Your dict is: " + str(self.cards) 
        return rep

    def add(self,card):
        self.cards.append(card)


    def shuffle(self):
        """Mix cards"""
        import random
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def fill_dict(self):
        for rank in Card.RANKS:
            for suit in Card.SUITS:
                self.add(Card(rank, suit))
        self.shuffle

def main():
    x = Dict()
    x.fill_dict()
    print(x)
main()
```

Comment: `__str__` - это метод, а не модуль.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы должны получить строковое представление для каждой карты отдельно, вместо взятия строкового представления для списка целиком.

***Пример:***

```py
...
def __str__(self):
    rep = "Your dict is: " + str(list(map(str, self.cards)))
    return rep
...
```

***stdout:***

```html
Your dict is: ['Ac', 'Ad', 'Ah', 'As', '2c', '2d', '2h', '2s', '3c', '3d', '3h', '3s', '4c', '4d', '4h', '4s', '5c', '5d', '5h', '5s', '6c', '6d', '6h', '6s', '7c', '7d', '7h', '7s', '8c', '8d', '8h', '8s', '9c', '9d', '9h', '9s', '10c', '10d', '10h', '10s', 'Jc', 'Jd', 'Jh', 'Js', 'Qc', 'Qd', 'Qh', 'Qs', 'Kc', 'Kd', 'Kh', 'Ks']
```